# Join a VM in one VNET to a Domain Controller in another VNET with VNET peering

Tags: azure

I have a resource group with a generic windows server and want to join it to a domain controller which resides in another resource group and VNET. I have set up VNET peering between the VNETS and can ping the IP Address of the domain controller from the windows server with no problem. However when i try to join the windows server to the domain it saas it cannot find the domain controller. I tried to change the DNS ip of the network card to the IP of the Domain controller but then I lose connection to the VM. Can anyone advise?

Comment: Please restart that Azure VM via Azure portal, and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Yo!

I had the same problem, where rebooting the VM was not solving the issue.

I resolved this by doing the following:

1. On the DC use the DC's actual ip address as the preferred DNS server and use 127.0.0.1 as the secondary DNS server. (I did this through setting the DNS on the NIC of the DC via Azure Portal)
2. On the client use the DC's actual ip address as the primary DNS server and leave the secondary DNS server blank. (Again, I did this through setting the DNS on the NIC of the DC via Azure Portal)
3. Make sure that the virtual network you created in Azure has your internal IP address of the domain controller listed, please go to AZURE portal and select the VNET to which the CLIENT(END POINTS) belongs go to DNS and change it from Microsoft DNS to Custom and put the IP of the Domain Controller.

Once the above was completed - I could join the domain with the vm in a different Vnet.

(8 months too late, Im sure you've found a solution by now, but I hope this helps someone!)